# Why is my filter not displaying in active admin's search status sidebar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, activeadmin, sidebar

I have an active admin application that I've been using for a while now. I have recently been trying to upgrade the rails version and all the gems along with it. I can't seem to get active admin to recognize the filter I'm using in its 'search status' sidebar though:

[Sidebar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbqyi.png)

This is a custom filter using checkboxes, and in the model it has a ransackable scope defined. The other filters update the 'search status' sidebar, but not this one. Is there something I have to add/change to get this to show up in the current filters list?

Comment: Hi Terry, have you looked at API changes for filters in ActiveAdmin? You should post relevant code, even if it used to work and that's not what you specifically changed...

Comment: The filter works, it just doesn't show up in the list of applied filters after it's used. Here's the filter as defined though:

`filter :status, as: :check_boxes, label: "BY STATUS", collection: proc {["open", "closed", "preview", "future"]}`

Comment: Which versions of ActiveAdmin and Rails? It may be a resolved issue.

Comment: rails 5.2.4.2, active_admin 2.7.0

Comment: I tried in one of my own projects and this should work. What is the resource you have registered? Does that resource have an association like ```belongs_to :status```, perhaps you have a custom instance method in your model ```def status```. To be able to help you we would need more context, like: database structure of the model.

Comment: status (in this model) is a custom ransackable scope. the status_in proc gathers up all the options passed into the filter and runs a sql query on the dates and times involved. there is no association